# Calculating the number of consecutive periods that match a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Given the data in the `Date` and `Close` columns, I'd like to calculate the values in the `ConsecPeriodsUp` column. This column gives the number of consecutive two-week periods that the `Close` value has increased.

```
Date        Close       UpThisPeriod    ConsecPeriodsUp                 
23/12/2015  3           1               1
16/12/2015  2           0               0
09/12/2015  1           0               0
02/12/2015  3           1               1
25/11/2015  2           0               0
18/11/2015  1           0               0
11/11/2015  7           1               3
04/11/2015  6           1               3
28/10/2015  5           1               2
21/10/2015  4           1               2
14/10/2015  3           1               1
07/10/2015  2           NaN             NaN
30/09/2015  1           NaN             NaN
```

I've written the following code to give the `UpThisPeriod` column but I can't see how I would aggregate that to get the `ConsecPeriodsUp` column, or whether there is way to do it in a single calculation that I'm missing.

```
import pandas as pd


def up_over_period(s):
    return s[0] >= s[-1]


df = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")

period = 3  # one more than the number of weeks

df['UpThisPeriod'] = pd.rolling_apply(
    df['Close'], 
    window=period, 
    func=up_over_period, 
    ).shift(-period + 1)
```

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: Expected output is in the `ConsecPeriodsUp` column. The input is just `Date` and `Close`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adapting the `groupby`, `shift` and `cumsum` trick described in the Pandas Cookbook, [Grouping like Python’s itertools.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#grouping). The main change is in dividing by the length of the period - 1 and then using the `ceil` function to round up to the next integer.

```
from math import ceil
...

s = df['UpThisPeriod'][::-1]

df['ConsecPeriodsUp'] = (s.groupby((s != s.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum() / (period - 1)).apply(ceil)
```